# Are there any other ways for infinite product to diverge/converge to zero (other than two mentioned in description)

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

An infinite product of complex terms can diverge/converge to zero if

(a) one or more of the terms are zero and all other terms are finite

or

(b) infinitely many terms have $ |z| < 1 $ and atmost finite terms are such that $ 1 < |z| < \infty $

Examples: 
$$ P_1 = 2e^{i\theta} \cdot 1e^{i2\theta} \cdot \frac{1}{2}e^{i3\theta} \cdot \frac{1}{4}e^{i4\theta} \cdots $$
$$ P_2 = \frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta} \cdot \frac{3}{4}e^{i\theta} \cdot \frac{7}{8}e^{i\theta} \cdot \frac{15}{16}e^{i\theta}  \cdots $$

Are there any other reasons for an infinite product $ \prod_{n=0}^\infty z_n $ to converge/diverge to zero? ($ z_n \in \mathbb {C} $)

Comment: What do you mean by converge/diverge to zero? How can a product _diverge_ to zero?

Comment: This is a convention (to the best of my knowledge) Here is an excerpt from wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product: [T]he product is said to converge when the limit exists and is not zero. Otherwise the product is said to diverge. A limit of zero is treated specially in order to obtain results analogous to those for infinite sums. Some sources allow convergence to 0 if there are only a finite number of zero factors and the product of the non-zero factors is non-zero...

Comment: The link is included in my comment above (between wikipedia and : [T])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a third possibility. You can have infinitely many terms with $|z|<1$ and infinitely many terms with $|z|>1$. Example:
$$
\frac{1}{1}\bigl(1+\frac{1}{1}\Bigr)\frac{1}{2}\bigl(1+\frac{1}{4}\Bigr)\frac{1}{3}\bigl(1+\frac{1}{9}\Bigr)\dots
$$

Comment: Great example! What kind of conditions should such product obey to diverge to zero? Should it be restrictive like: every finitely many consecutive set of terms should have product satisfying $ |z_i z_{i+1} ... z_{i+m}|  < 1 $ ? (In the example you give, we have every pair yielding product < 1, it could be variable number of finite terms) That is, it should be reduce-able to example b in the question (without changing the order to avoid Riemann paradox like situation, of course) Or something less restrictive than this? Thanks.